# How to retrieve child data from firebase realtime database on Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I am facing with firebase problem for 2 days and couldn't handle it.

Here is my realtime database

[image]

I am getting content, publishdate, source etc. but tags.

I want to get "0:100"  value that child of tags.  Here is my code:

Could you please help me ?

```
databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
  if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String] {
    let newsTitle = valueDictionary["title"]
    let newsImage = valueDictionary["imageUrl"]
    let publishData = valueDictionary["publishData"]
    let content = valueDictionary["content"]
    let tags = valueDictionary["tags"]

    self.news.insert(newsStruct(newsTitle: newsTitle, newsImage: newsImage, publishData: publishData, content: content, tags: tags), at: 0)

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableViewTagsNews.reloadData()
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple posts like this

```
posts
   0
      tags
         0: 100
         1: 200
   1
      tags
         0: 100
         1: 200
```

Here's the code that will iterate over each post, one at a time, read the content and then read the tags and output them to the console.

```
func readPostTags() {
    let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
    postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let content = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "creation_date").value as! String
        let tagsSnap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "tags")
        let allChildTagsSnap = tagsSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for tagChildSnap in allChildTagsSnap {
            let key = tagChildSnap.key
            let value = tagChildSnap.value as! Int
            print(content, key, value)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
0 100
1 200
0 100
1 200
```

Keep in mind that .childAdded will leave an observer on that node and notify you of further additions.

Comment: Thanks you its worked! i have another question. what if i just wanna get the first children ?

Comment: Yes. first child of tags.

Comment: @Oguz There are a couple of options. If you know the specific path the the node in question, you can access it directly. So for example `let pathToTag = fbRef.child("posts").child("0)".child("tags").child("0")` and observe that node with .observeSingleEvent and get the value from the Snapshot, which would be 100 in this case. I don't like to put extensive code in comments as it's hard to read but that may get you going. If not, ask a separate question with the code you've tried and we will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s because you’re casting the dictionary so its values are Strings only: `if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]` so the key value pair that does not have a string as its value gets lost in the conversion.

Instead, cast `snapshot.value` as `[String: Any]` and then get the tags like this: `let tags: Int = valueDictionary[“tags”] ?? 0`.

Comment: then what would be the data type for tag? would it be a range ?

Comment: im getting this.
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0